# Facebook Share Button Not Rendering in IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-sharer

I have the following code for a facebook Share button* on my page.

```
            <a name="fb_share" share_url="<?php echo $url;?>"></a> 
            <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
                    type="text/javascript">
            </script>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, the above script renders an iframe with the share button.
However in IE, the above script sits there and doesn't do anything.

Anyone have any ideas as to why? Thanks

*(for my particular application, share is more suitable than 'Like' and 'Send')

Comment: have you tried Developer Tools of IE.What tool is Saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The share button is deprecated.
I recomend you to do this:

```
<a href="//www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(YOUR_URL);?>" target="_blank">
    <img alt="Share" src="URL_OF_ANY_IMAGE">
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. It sounded to me like sharing it was totally deprecated as I couldn't find anything about it on the facebook developers site .But this works great. Do you know where there might be documentation on this?

Comment: You could see the official documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ in the end of the page (What happened to the old Share button?)